# Make Azure Functions not publicly accessible?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Currently my functions are accessible publicly. Is there a way to make it so that they can only be accessed via something else, like an API gateway, and not directly? I tried adding a VNET via the "networking" blade but I don't think that did anything (I could still call the functions publicly)...I think that just makes it so the functions could access resources on a private network. I didn't see any options in the settings to make the IP private. I'm not very well versed in networking related issues, so apologies if I'm being unclear.

Comment: I would have used App Service Environment for that but Function App seems not (yet) be available in the "Available App Types" selection

Comment: @KaiWalter Unfortunately Functions isn't listed in that UI, but you just need to do a top level create, choosing "App Service Plan" as the hosting option for the Function App.

Comment: See also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241431/azure-functions-can-you-use-web-config-restrictions-e-g-ip-restriction-or-bas

Comment: And also ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179256/azure-functions-and-restricting-ips

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [built-in keys support](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#working-with-keys) is meant to provide an option for this. You can require all requests to include an API key which is only shared with resources you care about. In fact, all HTTP-triggered functions require a key by default. You would have to explicitly choose to remove this requirement.

Keys aren't a networking solution though, and if you leak the keys, someone could access your APIs (until you roll the keys). You are correct that the VNet support is point-to-site, meaning it can access resources, but the function app is not protected itself. An App Service Environment would solve that, although Kai's comment on the original question is correct - ASE is not yet available for Functions.

In addition to keys, you could look at using [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) to require an AAD service principal. This is effectively like a key, but has additional benefits if you are modeling other entities in AAD. Unless you know you need this, though, I would stick with keys.

Answer (score 1):

With CORS functionnality you can restrict access to your Azure Function. To configure this, check the following link : [Azure Function Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings), at the CORS section.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply access restrictions to an Azure Function. The documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).

You can use PowerShell AZ module to create a rule (or the portal if you prefer).

```bsh
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule `
    -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" `
    -WebAppName "AppName" `
    -Name "Ip example rule" `
    -Priority 100 `
    -Action Allow `
    -IpAddress 122.133.144.0/24
```

Docs for `Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/add-azwebappaccessrestrictionrule?view=azps-3.7.0).

Answer (score 0):

IP restrictions can be used to restrict access to whitelisted IPs. You can do it via the the Portal -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions

or in the web.config with ipSecurity