# Azure Functions and restricting IPs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would really like to use Azure Functions for an upcoming project, but is there a way to create a whitelist of IPs like in ipSecurity in Web.Config?

They are using `authLevel` function, so there is some protection there. My customer has a security requirement for a whitelist.

Looking at the resource explorer there seems to be a property *ipSecurityRestrictions* that might work, but I don't see it on my Azure function instance.

Comment: I think you can associate you Function App with App Service Environment (ASE) and setup access via NSG as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you don't have control over a web.config this isn't doable that way.

You could do the ip validation within the function itself or add a solution like API Management to block traffic.

If you're willing to run on dedicated (not consumption plan), you can deploy the functions runtime as a site extension with a modified web.config with the ip whitelist you need: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Deploying-the-Functions-runtime-as-a-private-site-extension

Comment: Thanks for the info! I guess an in-function check it is.

Comment: Any official Azure statement/indication on the fact that custom `web.config` doesn't apply to Functions Apps?.

Comment: i know this is over a year old now.. but is this still the case? i have a series of functions all running in the same funciton app, and i only need to restrict one of them to allow certain ip range to connect... is still the recommended way?

Comment: @m1nkeh It looks like it is now supported. Please reference https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/18835420-restrict-ips-in-azure-functions-proxies?tracking_code=63ab1545c0b83b333001d5fc24394c2e

Comment: @robjam Looks like using IP access rules is not the best way for "consumption plan" function apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses because your IPs might change frequently. Application Gateway looks like the best option for now, but it can get expensive. What did you go with?

Comment: @GerhardLiebenberg
Should be supported now `This is now possible using the “IP Restrictions” functionality available under “Platform Features” > “Networking” `
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/18835420-restrict-ips-in-azure-functions-proxies?tracking_code=63ab1545c0b83b333001d5fc24394c2e

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, IP whitelisting has been introduced and is available for the Azure Functions consumption plan (standard and premium). Step-by-step guide:

1. First, go to your Azure Portal and select your **Azure Function resource**
2. Next, select **Networking**
3. Select **Configure Access Restrictions**
   [image]
4. Define your list of **allow/deny rules** as desired to control traffic to your Azure Function