# Application Insights Trace Listener with azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a bunch of services which emit `System.Diagnostics.Trace.*` trace messages and when hosted via webapi, I simply include the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener` package and my traces are collected in app insights.  However, part of the setup requires a web.config file to tell the trace listener to listen and flush like:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="TraceLogging" switchName="Verbose">
      <listeners>
        <add name="appinsights" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179256/azure-functions-and-restricting-ips) it doesn't seem like I can setup this up via web.confg.

Is there any way to enable the trace listener to send traces to my app insights?

Answer (score 0):

There are plans to expose configuration and logging providers extensibility that would enable scenarios like this, but this is not currently supported.

Comment: Is there another way to enable the trace listener to pick up traces outside of web.config?

Comment: Yes, you can register additional listeners by simply adding them to the Trace.Listeners collection. Working with sources it's a bit more cumbersome, but doable.

Comment: Where to do that in a functions app?  Is there a startup or similar place that I can run once when it starts and that's it or I gotta do Lazy<T> etc?

Comment: There is no startup hook. Currently, you could simply add a static check that handles this logic when the function runs (or a static constructor if using pre-compiled functions)

Comment: OK, I'll see what I can do.  static constructor may work if I have some sort of other guards.  I'd have to add to each class in the function app containing functions though :(  Hopefully something comes along soon to support this scenario better.  I hate losing all my insights :)