# Is it possible to use custom trace listeners/config with Azure Function apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm working on a new Azure Function App (AFA) as part of a larger application. The AFA is a C# DLL and it references other DLLs common to the application. The larger application has custom trace listeners that funnel tracing to a SQL database and attach additional information to the messages. We configure this via `App.config`/`Web.config`. I'm having trouble understanding how this should work in a C# DLL library AFA (or if it can't work).

In the `App.config` file we define a connection string for the (EF) database, a shared listener, sources, a switch, and add listeners. E.g.:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... lots of stuff ... -->
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyAppLogDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="..."/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="sql" type="MyApp.EntityFrameworkTraceListener, MyApp" initializeData="MyApp">
                <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Information" />
            </add>
            <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener">
                <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Verbose" />
            </add>
        </sharedListeners>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="sql" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="MyApp" switchName="default" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="console" />
                    <add name="sql" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="default" value="Verbose" />
        </switches>
        <trace autoflush="true" useGlobalLock="false">
            <listeners>
                <add name="console" />
                <add name="sql" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" maxMessagesToLog="2147483647" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="256000" />
        </diagnostics>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Regarding the `system.serviceModel` element: we also use this config to capture and log WCF XML messages to help debug API issues with third parties.

Typically when we trace a message, we use a custom `TraceSource`, which automatically fills in the extra bits, but we have normal `Trace.TraceInformation` and `WriteLine` type calls also.

Is there a way to replicate this with an Azure Function App? Do I need to hard-code this stuff and create it all in code?

**Update 1:** To be clear, the original config didn't work (I didn't really expect it to magically work). I tried creating the listener in code and adding it to the diagnostics collection, but that didn't work either. I'm testing via a local AFA host (NPM package `func host start`) and they neither get logged to the console/host nor the database. Nuts.

**Update 2:** Even writing to the DB directly doesn't work, but no errors are logged. It just silently does nothing when I call SaveChanges...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46004707/1171619

Comment: That comment is why I tried adding it to Listeners manually, but that didn't work either (no errors).

Comment: I was able to get it working by creating my own source, switch and listener and connecting them all together. The EF part is another major problem but as far as tracing goes it does work if done entirely in code.