# Is there a way to attach the Azure Functions host logger to normal C# tracing?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk, azure-functions-runtime

I have an Azure Function app that uses other DLLs. I'm trying to get the logging from those DLLs, which uses TraceSource or Trace.*, to show up in the azure functions/webjobs host window when running locally (and hopefully when running in Azure). Is there any way to connect them, like adding a TraceListener statically that pipes into the host?

Comment: Is it the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057549/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-trace-listeners-config-with-azure-function-apps ?

Comment: It's the other direction

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution for wiring up a `TraceListener` here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/688. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That's the other direction. I don't want to add a listener. There already is one (or something) that the Azure Functions host uses to display things logged via the `TraceWriter` parameter in each function, but normal tracing doesn't seem to go to it.

Comment: You have a library that uses `Trace.Writeline()` (or similar) and want it to go to the Functions logs? That link shows how you can to wire up a Listener that pushes those traces through the TraceWriter. Nothing in Functions/WebJobs explicitly looks for traces like that today, so you'd need to wire one up and send it through the Functions TraceWriter.