# Azure Functions without public endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there a way to deploy some code as an Azure Function, but not expose it publicly? From what I see in documentation, AF always gets a public endpoint. Is that the only solution? I would like to build a solution in which AF are accessible only internally, by services which are behind firewall (no public access either). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only HTTP trigger functions get a public endpoint. All other functions do not.

So you could create a queue trigger function, which has no public endpoint, and then have an internal service place a message in the queue that would cause the function to trigger.

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising. One question, though. How these functions work? I mean, if I put 1000 messages in a queue, which triggers function to start, am I going to have 1000 function instances working in parallel? Or is it  configurable?

Comment: Each message will trigger a function to execute. If you host your function app in the Consumption plan (aka "serverless"), then Azure will scale your function app out to multiple instances as needed.

Comment: Yes, perhaps to multiple instances, but not instantly start up 1000 instances. In my experience it will try to take about 10 items from the queue immediately, probably just in separate threads and not in different instances. It may take up to 10 minutes before it slowly starts to scale up.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer - No. If you're using the managed version through the Azure Portal, it's a public-facing service. 
However, there are some options that require more work on your part:

1. There is an on-premise Azure Functions. You can get more details about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview
2. Azure Functions is open-source. You can deploy it yourself. The repro and more instructions are at: https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script

Answer (score 0):

You can apply access restrictions to an Azure Function. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147830/607701).